# Como organizar DIVs en mosaico (con diferentes alturas)?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, div

### Ayuda con la organización de divs con float

Página de post con diferentes alturas, para presentar proyectos y noticias en una página web.

[ejemplo de la lista de post](https://www.joaquinlois.com/videos-audio/)

Intento hacer una retícula donde se muestren los proyectos en tres columnas, pero ordenados de izquierda a derecha por orden de filas organización en Z. Hasta ahora he probado con dos métodos y cada uno tiene sus problemas.

He intentado hacerlo con css, pero creo que la solución tiene que ser con java script. Agradecería mucho algo de luz. Llevo mucho tiempo intentando hacer algo así.

[image: Esta es la estructura que quiero y los resultados de los dos métodos que he probado]

---

### 1 Div float left

Esta sería la mejor solución, pero cuando los divs tienen diferentes alturas estos se desorganizan. Una solución sería dar a todos los div la misma altura, pero con esto no consigo el efecto que pretendo. A modo de galería en mosaico, o algo similar. Me crea estructuras como la que mostraba la imagen anterior.

```css
article{
  background:#ccc; 
  width:33%; 
  float:left; padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip:content-box;
  text-align: center;}
```

```html
<article> <h3>1</h3> <p>div altura 1 linea</p></article>
<article> <h3>2</h3> <p>div altura 1 linea</p></article>
<article> <h3>3</h3> <p><br> 3<br> lineas</p></article>
<article> <h3>4</h3><br> <p>3 lineas<br> Me gustaría que este div se pegara al (1) superior, no al anterior</p></article>
<article> <h3>5</h3><br><p> lineas<br>lineas</p></article>
<article> <h3>6</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
<article> <h3>7</h3> <br><p> En este caso el alineamiento no queda a la izquierda</p> </article>
<article> <h3>8</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
<article> <h3>9</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
```

---

### 2 Multiple colums

Esta es la solución que estoy usando actualmente, Visualmente es lo que estoy buscando, pero el orden es erróneo, ya que lo ordena por columnas y en muchos casos post como el nº3 acaban al final de la página, por lo que no muestro en órden cronológico, no como pretendo. Ademas a esto hay que sumarle que con el *responsive* las columnas varían y el orden también.

```js
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

```css
.contenedor {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
article {
  break-inside: avoid;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">
<article> <h3>1</h3> <p>div altura 1 linea</p></article>
<article> <h3>2</h3> <p>div altura 1 linea</p></article>
<article> <h3>3</h3> <p><br> 3<br> lineas</p></article>
<article> <h3>4</h3><br> <p>3 lineas<br> Me gustaría que este div se pegara al (1) </p></article>
<article> <h3>5</h3><br><p> lineas<br>lineas</p></article>
<article> <h3>6</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
<article> <h3>7</h3> <br><p> En este caso el alineamiento no queda a la izquierda</p> </article>
<article> <h3>8</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
<article> <h3>9</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
  
</div>
```

---

### 3 Masonry

```js
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100');
body{background:#333;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:19px;}
h3{ font-size:35px; font-weight:100; margin-left:10px; color:#fff;}
article {
  break-inside: avoid;
  background: #d9db68;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h3>Masonry</h3>
  <div class="grid">
    <article class="grid-item"> <h3>1</h3> <p>div altura 1 linea</p></article>
    <article class="grid-item"> <h3>2</h3> <p>div altura 1 linea</p></article>
    <article class="grid-item"> <h3>3</h3> <p><br> 3<br> lineas</p></article>
    <article class="grid-item"> <h3>4</h3><br> <p>3 lineas<br> Me gustaría que este div se pegara al (1)     </p></article>
    <article class="grid-item"> <h3>5</h3><br><p> lineas<br>lineas</p></article>
    <article class="grid-item"> <h3>6</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
    <article class="grid-item"> <h3>7</h3> <br><p> En este caso el alineamiento no queda a la izquierda</p> </article>
    <article class="grid-item"> <h3>8</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
    <article class="grid-item"> <h3>9</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
  
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: bienvenido a la comunidad, te informo para poder colaborarte tienes que formular una buena pregunta, publicando un codigo minimo, completo y verificable.

Comment: No te vamos a escribir el código desde 0, por lo menos publica lo que has intentado hasta ahora......

Comment: Perdón, soy nuevo aquí, es la primera vez que escribo. Creía que con la imagen y el link de la página se entendia, sorryy 

He creado un ejemplo de los dos métodos que he intentado.

Saludos.

Comment: Me gusta la segunda versión, sin embargo, usando el layout de columnas el orden será vertical. Si no te quieres complicar, puedes usar la librería [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/); es muy útil y práctica.

Comment: Si quieres una opción CSS puedes probar con [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). La pega aquí es que todos los items dentro del contenedor serán alineados verticalmente a la misma altura. Puedes verlo en [éste fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/yLd3cqws/1) que te he preparado. Una mejor y moderna opción sería usar [Grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) pero aún no tiene soporte suficiente (muy pronto :)). La buena noticia es que hay un [polyfill](https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

Existe una libreria especializada en el problema que tienes se llama **isotope**.Una alternativa seria usar esta libreria http://isotope.metafizzy.co/, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 80
  }
});

$('.append-button').on( 'click', function() {
  // create new item elements
  var $items = getItemElement();
  // append elements to container
  $grid.append( $items )
    // add and lay out newly appended elements
    .isotope( 'appended', $items );
});


// make <div class="grid-item grid-item--width# grid-item--height#" />
function getItemElement() {
  var $item = $('<div class="grid-item"></div>');
  // add width and height class
  var wRand = Math.random();
  var hRand = Math.random();
  var widthClass = wRand > 0.85 ? 'grid-item--width3' : wRand > 0.7 ? 'grid-item--width2' : '';
  var heightClass = hRand > 0.85 ? 'grid-item--height3' : hRand > 0.5 ? 'grid-item--height2' : '';
  $item.addClass( widthClass ).addClass( heightClass );
  return $item;
}
```

```css
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #0D8;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
}

.grid-item--width2 { width: 160px; }
.grid-item--height2 { height: 160px; }

.grid-item--width3 { width: 240px; }
.grid-item--height3 { height: 240px; }

button { font-size: 20px; }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.1/isotope.pkgd.js'></script>

<h1>Isotope</h1>

<p><button class="append-button">insertar</button></p>

<div class="grid">
  
</div>
```

otra ayuda que te daria seria alinear con left y right

```css
#contenedor{
  width:328px;
  display:inline-block;
}
article{
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:#CCC;
 margin:2px;
  text-align:center;
height:auto;
}

.uno{float:left;}
.dos{float:right;}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
<article class="uno"> <h3>1</h3> <p>div altura 1 linea</p></article>
<article class="uno"> <h3>2</h3> <p>div altura 1 linea</p></article>
<article class="uno"> <h3>3</h3> <p><br> 3<br> lineas</p></article>

<article class="uno"> <h3>4</h3><br> <p>3 lineas<br> Me gustaría que este div </p></article>
<article class="uno"> <h3>5</h3><br><p> lineas<br>lineas</p></article>
<article class="dos"> <h3>6</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
<article class="dos"> <h3>7</h3> <br><p> En este caso el alineamiento no queda a la izquierda</p> </article>
<article class="dos"> <h3>8</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
<article class="uno"> <h3>9</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
<article class="dos"> <h3>10</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
<article class="uno"> <h3>11</h3> <br><p> lineas</p></article>
</div>
```